# Help in understanding 4.15 Integral Theorem Bak Newman Complex Analysis Book

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm reading the book Complex Analysis by Bak and Newman.

I understand everything in the proof below - except for the constant 2 in the bound. Can someone explain me where the factor of 2 comes?

Few notational clarifications: For complex $a$ and $b$, $a << b$ means $|a| \leq |b|$

ML theorem refers to a theorem that says that a curve integral can be bound by the maximum value $M$ and the length $L$.

I've tried to point the step that confuses me with a red circle. I don't know where the factor of 2 comes in that bound. Length is $h$ and the integral should be bounded by $\epsilon$, thus $h \epsilon$ ? So where does $2h \epsilon$ come from? Both bounds are okay for the proof but I'm just curious if I'm missing something.

[image: Excerpt from the textbook 1]
[image]

Comment: You are integrating over two line segments, each of length $|h|$. You could improve $2$ to $\sqrt2$...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How are there two line segments? I thought there was only one of length $|h|$? There are two line segments in a sense but one is $\Re (h)$ and the other is $\Im (h)$?

Comment: Make that length $\le|h|$.

Comment: I see what you are saying. There are two segments, $\Re(h)$ and $\Im(h)$ and both are less than $|h|$. Somehow, I forgot about the path (defined earlier in the proof) and thought we were going from $z$ to $z+h$ directly on a straight line. Thanks it makes sense, now. If you want to write this explanation as an answer, I'll accept it.